# Elasticsearch 5.0 and Elasticsearch-Spark connector - what is correct maven artefact

Tags: java, elasticsearch-hadoop, elasticsearch-spark

When writing application to run on Apache Spark 1.6 using Elasticsearch-Spark connector, documentation at (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/5.0/install.html#_minimalistic_binaries) says to use maven artefact

`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>`

However maven fails with error message that specified artefact cannot be found. After searching through maven central I found however alternative versions:

For Spark 1.3+

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

For Spark 2.*

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got the answer from ES folks. It is a bug in documentation, going to be fixed soon. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/890#issuecomment-258511400